# Running tf.where and getting TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Some background on what I am trying to achieve: I'm trying to implement [this](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall17/compsci527/notes/hog.pdf) implementation of a HOG feature extractor as a keras Lambda layer. While I do have a small amount of experience with Tensorflow, writing something this complex is slightly above my level of expertise. Needless to say, I'm having a few issues.

Just so it's easy to understand what my model is, here is the structure, where `x_conv` and `y_conv` are the only parts of my implementation that have trainable parameters.

```
# Model 
inputs = Input(shape(128, 128)
x_conv = conv2d(1, (3,3), strides=1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=init_prewitt_x)(inputs)
y_conv = conv2d(1, (3,3), strides=1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=init_prewitt_y)(inputs)
conv_stacked = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x_conv, y_conv])
x = Lambda(hog_layer, output_shape=hoglayer_output_shape)(conv_stacked)
```

and my hyperparameters, initializers and the fake batch I use to test `hog_layer` are

```
# Defining Initializers
prewitt_x = np.array([[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]])
prewitt_y = prewitt_x.T 

def init_prewitt_x(shape, dtype=None):
return K.convert_to_tensor(prewitt_x)

def init_prewitt_y(shape, dtype=None):
    return K.convert_to_tensor(prewitt_y)

# Defining Values
bins = 8         # number of gaps
w = 360/bins     # gap size
centers = np.arange(0, 360, w)+0.5*w

cell_size = 8
block_size = 2
batch_size = 20

fake_batch = np.random.rand(20, 128, 128, 2)
```

The part which is giving me trouble is the `hog_layer`. There are no trainable parameters within the layer, just a series of tensor transformations. It is also not the complete HOG feature extractor - the batch selection and normalization process is yet to be implemented. What is shown bellow takes the stacked outputs of `x_conv` and `y_conv` and returns (or at least it will once it works), an array with the shape (batches, image height/number of cells, image width/number of cells, bins in histogram). Here is it:

```
def hog_layer(conv_stacked_batch):
    #Finding the value of the last axis
    axis = tf.size(tf.shape(conv_stacked_batch))-1 # Ask if considers batch_dim!!!!

    #Splitting along axis to x_conv and y_conv
    x_grad, y_grad = tf.split(conv_stacked_batch,2, axis=axis)

    # Defining Empty Vote Array for shape (batch_size, img height, img width, bins)
    votes_array = tf.zeros((batch_size, tf.shape(x_grad)[1], tf.shape(x_grad)[2], bins)) 

    def hog_layer_img(votes_array, img_nb,x_grad, y_grad):
        #Calculating magnitudes
        mags = tf.sqrt(tf.pow(x_grad[img_nb, :, :], 2)+tf.pow(y_grad[img_nb, :, :], 2))

        #Calculating angles from 0 to 360 degrees
        angles = 180*(tf.atan2(y_grad[img_nb, :, :], x_grad[img_nb, :, :]) + np.pi)/np.pi 

        # Defining the function that generates all votes for each bin number
        def create_vote_array(votes_array, angles, mags, bin_nb):
            # The Else function is for all bins expect for the last bin
            # Voting for angles that lie in the last bin act differently (see bellow)

            # For angles in bin number (bin_nb=j), where bin j has boundries center[i] to center[i+1]
            # where bin j has boundries center[i] to center[i+1]
            # unless bin j is the last bin, then the boutreis are from the last center to the first center
            # If the bins=8, the center would be:
            # [ 22.5,   67.5,  112.5,  157.5,  202.5,  247.5,  292.5,  337.5]

            # Read --else-- comments first for explanation 
            if bin_nb == bins-1:
                # Since it is hard to express in python that an angle 0 = angle 360, we do this instead
                # Adding 360 to where the center and the angles are not both on the same side of the 0/360 boundary
                # This satisfies vote_j + vote_j+1 = mag
                votes_top_j = tf.where(centers[-1] < angles, tf.multiply(mags, (centers[0]-angle_array+360)/w), tf.zeros(tf.shape(angles)))
                votes_top_j1 = tf.where(centers[-1] < angles, tf.multiply(mags, (angle_array-centers[bin_nb])/w), tf.zeros(tf.shape(angles)))

                votes_bot_j = tf.where(centers[0] > angles, tf.multiply(mags, (centers[0]-angle_array)/w), tf.zeros(tf.shape(angles)))
                votes_bot_j1 = tf.where(centers[0] > angles, tf.multiply(mags, (360+angle_array-centers[bin_nb])/w), tf.zeros(tf.shape(angles)))


                votes_j = tf.add(votes_top_j, votes_bot_j)
                votes_j1 = tf.add(votes_top_j1, votes_bot_j1)

                votes_array[:, :, bin_nb] += votes_j
                votes_array[:, :, 0] += votes_j1

            # finds all angles in bin j
            # for those not in bin j, element = 0
            else:
                # Calculates votes for bin j for angles that are in bin j
                votes_j = tf.where((centers[bin_nb]) < angles < centers[bin_nb+1], tf.multiply(mags, (centers[bin_nb+1]-angles)/w), tf.zeros(tf.shape(angles)))

                #Calculates votes for bin j+1 for angles that are in bin j
                votes_j1 = tf.where((centers[bin_nb]) < angles < centers[bin_nb+1], tf.multiply(mags, (angle_array-centers[bin_nb])/w), tf.zeros(tf.shape(angles)))

                #Adds votes the bin jth and j+1th layer on axis=2 of voting array                            
                votes_array[img_nb, :, :, bin_nb] = tf.add(votes_array[img_nb, :, :, bin_nb], votes_j)
                votes_array[img_nb, :, :, bin_nb+1] = tf.add(votes_array[img_nb, :, :, bin_nb+1], votes_j1)

            return votes_array
            #Bin Level

        # Interating through each bin to generate votes                           
        for i in range(bins):
            votes_array = create_vote_array(votes_array, angles, mags, i)

        return votes_array
        # Image Level                            

    # Performing hog_layer_img function on each imgage in the batch
    for img_nb in range(batch_size):
        votes_array = hog_layer_img(votes_array, img_nb, x_grad, y_grad)

    # For each cell, calculating the average vote at each bin level (or depth)
    # We multiply each element by the number of pixels in the cell, giving the sum of the votes for each bin level   
    # Result is array that keeps the spatial infomation of the cells
    # and the last dimetion (with depth bins) is the cell histogram                            
    cell_array = (cell_size**2)*tf.nn.avg_pool(votes_array, ksize=(1, cell_size, cell_size, bins), strides=(1, cell_size, cell_size, 1))

    return cell_array
    # Batch Level
```

As you can likely see, there are some issues. The most obvious one is the lack of all the `tf.constant` and `tf.Variable`'s. The reason for this a. I have not gotten to it yet, and b. I'm not confident enough in my tensorflow abilities (i mainly use Keras) to do it without advice from someone more experienced.

Running this as it is now, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t 
is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use 
TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value 
of a tensor.
```

from the line

```
else:
   # Calculates votes for bin j for angles that are in bin j
   votes_j = tf.where((centers[bin_nb]) < angles < centers[bin_nb+1], tf.multiply(mags, (centers[bin_nb+1]-angles)/w), tf.zeros(tf.shape(angles)))
```

What I am trying to do is for every angle that lies within my specified range (all the angles that lie within bin i), I calculate it's 'vote' to bin i (and bin i + 1 in the next line). For those that are not within the specified range, it returns zeros. I do this so to maintain the same shape as the array of magnitudes (or `mags`) as to allow easy element-wise multiplication. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I can't think of any.

Another major issue comes from this operation:

```
votes_array[img_nb, :, :, bin_nb] = tf.add(votes_array[img_nb, :, :, bin_nb], votes_j)
```

I know this will not work for tensors, but I do not know the equivalent operation. Other online examples are extremely unhelpful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
(centers[bin_nb]) < angles < centers[bin_nb+1]
```

Python interprets:

```
(centers[bin_nb]) < angles and angles < centers[bin_nb+1]
```

But both left and right hand sides of that `and` are tensors, and tensors cannot be used as boolean values. What you want is a member-wise logical and, which you can get with:

```
((centers[bin_nb]) < angles) & (angles < centers[bin_nb+1])
```

As for the assignment operation to a variable, that should be a separate question, but basically you have to build the tensor yourself piece by piece. You can put the pieces into lists and then use `tf.concat` and/or `tf.stack` to build the complete tensor.